# Is there a way to use my mobile as emulator in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio

I already started USB debugging but vs2017 still not showing my device for xamarin .Anyone know  how to do it?

Comment: You don't even mention the phone model. Nothing works out of the box due to phone vendors. Make sure that you don't expect readers to have magic to read your mind.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure your mobile's developer mode is unlocked.
2. Make sure the USB driver of your mobile is installed. Normally should be covered by USB driver in Android SDK.
3. Make sure you accept any security warning dialog popup in your mobile when you plug in you mobile to the PC.
4. Sometimes restart adb server or restart mobile can solve the problem.
5. Make sure your mobile Android version is within the support version for your project.